# Is $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $L^p$-sense?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Is $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $L^p$-sense? Intuitively if we "smoothen" the sharp edges of $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then it seems possible to get a sequence of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions converging to $f$. But I can't write down it mathematically. I have a feeling that I may make a use of the Fourier theory, but I don't know each Fourier sum of $f$, $S_N(F)=\sum_{n=1}^N \hat f(n)\phi(n)$ is whether in $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or not. the orthonormal basis $\{\phi(n)\}_n$ is usually taken to be $\{e^{inx}\}_n$, so they are in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $\hat f(n)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(t)e^{-int}dt$ is a number, so at least I know that $S_N(f)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But in general it is not in $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Here $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is infinitely many times differentiable and compactly supported and $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is continuous and compactly supported.

Comment: The usual trick here is mollification - let $\phi_k \in C^\infty_0$ converge to the Dirac delta and consider the convolutions $\phi_k * f$.

Comment: Note that $C_0$ is not contained in $L^p.$

Comment: @zhw. I suggest that you provide an example of $f \in C_0 \setminus L^p$.

Comment: @md2perpe Oh. You're right. I see now that $C_0$ here has an unusual definition. $C_0$ more often denotes the continuous functions that $\to 0$ at $\infty.$ Here it means compactly supported, which is usually denoted $C_c.$

Comment: @zhw. Even if $C_0$ had its usual definition, I think that it would be good to provide an example.

Comment: @md2perpe  On $\mathbb R$ you have things like $1/(1+|x|).$ This $\to 0$ at $\pm \infty$ but is not in $L^1.$ Take $p$th roots to get counterexamples for $L^p.$